# Como descartar todas as alterações não commitadas?

Tags: git

Como descartar todas as alterações não commitadas?

Exemplo: tenho um projeto que possui algumas dezenas de commits, supondo que em um determinado momento resolvo descartar tudo **que ainda não foi confirmado via commit**, como posso fazer isso?

Obs: a grosso modo quero desfazer tudo até o commit anterior. Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 11):

Tenho usado com sucesso apenas estes dois comandos abaixo quando faço diversas alterações em uma branch e desejo me desfazer de todas elas **sem ter commitado nada ainda**.

O **primeiro** comando é para reverter todas as alterações em arquivos que estavam versionados:

```
git checkout -- .
```

O **segundo** é para apagar todos os arquivos e diretórios criados:

```
git clean -f -d
```

Ao último comando, você ainda pode acrescentar o `-x` para também apagar arquivos que foram criados mas estão sendo ignorados pelo git (portanto, não aparecem no `git status`).

Se você tiver adicionado arquivos no index (usando `git add`), você precisa aplicar o seguinte comando antes dos comandos acima, para removê-los do index:

```
git reset HEAD .
```

Answer (score 6):

Lista todos os commits que você já fez:

```
git log --stat
```

Vai listar os seus últimos commits, ai você escolhe um ID, pra onde quer voltar:

```
* 518ce00 
* ec3be16
* df9b821
* 8db3a02
* 698f520
* 19ccc39
```

Ai é só resetar ao ponto que você escolheu:

```
git reset --hard 19ccc39
```

Mas o ideal seria você trabalhar com branches, assim evitaria isso.

Answer (score 6):

Se você não fez `git add` / `git commit`, pode simplesmente:

```
git checkout .
```

ou deletar e clonar o projeto novamente

Comment: Também pode usar: git checkout nome_do_arquivo

Comment: Isso só funcionaria para arquivos que foram alterados mas ainda não foram comitados

Comment: É o que está sendo perguntado, arquivos não commitados

Comment: Opa, isso mesmo, o que não tiver sido commitado. `git checkout .` reverte: arquivos alterados, adicionados e excluídos que não tenham sido contemplados por um commit?

Comment: Isso mesmo, basicamente desfaz as alterações do projeto

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser descartar tudo permanentemente:

`git checkout .`

Se você quer voltar tudo, mas pode ser que se arrependa:

`git stash`

Answer (score 0):

Se voce ainda não deu um `git add .`, você pode dar um `git status` e ele vai te dar duas opções: `git add <file>...` e `git restore <file>...`. O `git restore <file>` vai descartar as modificações que você fez em um arquivo específico e o `git restore .` vai descartar todas as modificações feitas antes de serem adicionadas.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).